# Unexpected behavior for ConditionalOnBean in Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

I was trying examples to understand **@ConditionalOnBean** and came across such a situation that Conditional Bean gets initialized before the bean on which it is dependent. Below is my example,

> Main Class

```
  @SpringBootApplication
  @ComponentScan
  public class MainConditionalOnBean {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(MainConditionalOnBean.class, args);
      }

  }
```

> Class A

```
@Component
public class A {

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadA() {
        System.out.println("Loading A");
    }

    @Bean
    public B getB() {
        System.out.println("Loading B from A");
        return new B();
    }
}
```

> Class B

```
public class B {

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadB() {
        System.out.println("Loading B");
    }
}
```

> Class C

```
    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnBean(B.class)
    public class C {

        @PostConstruct
        public void loadC() {
            System.out.println("Loading C");
        }
    }
```

> OutPut

```
Loading A
Loading C
Loading B from A
Loading B
```

I am not able to understand why C is loading before B, as C is dependent on B itself.

As per definition in the wiki,

> Conditional that only matches when beans meeting all the specified requirements are already contained in the BeanFactory.

I am not getting how can bean factory contain bean which is not yet initialized.

Please, can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `@Configuration` or `@Component` on class `B`. In question, I do not see any such annotation.

Comment: What's the purpose of adding annotation over there? I have created Bean of B in Class A. And ultimately it's going to BeanFactory right?